# How do I set a variable inside a variable using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

I want to create a script that goes to a random url (english, french, and spanish, are just examples of url endings and not actual urls). There are probably better way to set variables, but I need it to be in this particular way because of the way the rest of the code is set up.

```
REM define list entries
set list[0]=english
set list[1]=french
set list[2]=spanish

REM create a random number, smaller than the list's length
set /a randomNum=(%RANDOM%*3/32768)
start "" http://youtube.com/%list[%randomNum%]%
```

This goes to `youtube.com/randomNum`, and not the value of the variables I set.

Any help getting it to go to `youtube.com/english` etc.?

Comment: Three words for you to research: Delayed Variable Expansion.

Comment: This page may be helpful for you: [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: `call start "" http://youtube.com/%%list[%randomNum%]%%` described in [Advanced usage : `CALL`ing internal commands](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html#advanced).

Comment: Use `start "" http://youtube.com/!list[%randomNum%]!` with Delayed Expansion Enabled and see: [arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: A side note: you can use [`%%` modulus](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions) as `set /a randomNum=%RANDOM%%%3` rather than `set /a randomNum=(%RANDOM%*3/32768)`